# @media selectors don't work as expected with new ruleset

Tags: html, css, media-queries

We have a static html page, looking something like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root">
      <p class="home-paragraph">
        Some very long text for testing the way the text will appear on different sized screens.
      </p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

We create some rules for a static page along the following lines:

```css
.home-paragraph {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 65%;
}
```

The goal we want to achieve is to change the styling rules when the screen size is reduced to 768px or less. To do this, we implement *different rules* with the `@media` method.

```css
.home-paragraph {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 65%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .home-paragraph {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0em 2em;
  }
}
```

**QUESTION**:

Why does my styling not appear to change when I change the screen size to 768px or less?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer in this case was pretty elusive to me due to the fact that the rule switch wasn't very easy to identify at a glance. What's happening is that the new rules are applied to the document when the size of the screen changes, but the old rules are not completely overriden. The `max-width: 65%;` line is never explicitly changed in the new media rule, and as such remains when the new rules are applied. Basically, the applied css starts as:

```css
.home-paragraph {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 65%;
}
```

When the screen size is changed to 768px or less, the applied css looks like...

```css
.home-paragraph {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 65%;
  padding: 0em 2em;
}
```

So the new styling is taking effect, but we haven't explicitly removed the old styling which we no longer want to use. By changing the media rule to...

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .home-paragraph {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: 0em 2em;
  }
}
```

The desired changes take effect. The text now expands to container and has the necessary padding.